# WPF Application with Image on button

Tags: wpf

I have created a WPF application. In that I need to show image on button . So that where should I store that image on my application and how to set source property of the image ??
Please replay

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Check "[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button x:Name="Button1" Width="200" Height="200" Content="Button1" Margin="0,0,0,400">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush **ImageSource ="Images/AERO.png"**  ></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

In CS File:( Store image in resources or any folder in Project Directory)

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/AERO.png"));
    Button1.Background = brush;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a image to your project.
2. Set this image's property : 'no copy' and 'Resource'
3. Add a Button,remove it's default 'Content' property.
4. Add a Image control as this Button's content.

---

```
   <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Height="42">
            <Image Source="pen.png" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add image on a button like,

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Images/imageName.png" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Or else you can try,

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="MyResource" ImageSource="Images/imageName.png" />
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Background="{StaticResource MyResource}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Else try this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="MyResource" ImageSource="Images/imageName.png" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button>
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="34" Height="19" Margin="0">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyResource"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add image to project and set the image properties:

1. Build Action: Resource
2. Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

Then in the .xaml file add a Button (for example):

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40">
     <Image Source="Resources/yourImageName.png" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Button>
```